# Post from Tumblr to Google+ using IFTTT

Tags: if-this-then-that

I'm using IFTTT to automatically post Tumblr posts to Facebook and Twitter.

These are 2 separate IFTTT recipes both using the Tumblr post as the starting point.

I'd also like to post to Google+. Is it possible to do this with IFTTT? I couldn't find the correct recipes to do this.

Comment: What about doing it the opposite way? Post to g+, have it then crosspost to tumblr, Facebook, twitter. This might be easier. (Perhaps write a script to scrape g+ when u have a new post... or see ale's answer about RSS feeds).

Comment: @vikarjramun unfortuatly the whole process starts with a photo post added to dropbox (which using IFTTT) is posted to tumblr (which using IFTTT) is posted to twitter and facebook. So the starting point also needs to allow IFTTT

Comment: just curious, but WHY??

Comment: @vikarjramun Its a photo blog, so the most intensive aspect of running it is sourcing the photos, from there they are dumped into a dropbox folder and then the rest of the pipeline manages its self courtesy of IFTTT. Previously we where still having to source the photos but manually posting them to each platform

Comment: Oh! That's actually brilliant! Sorry I couldn't help on the g+ part

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Google+ doesn't have an API that allows for posting, so IFTTT can't hook into G+ to write posts.

There may be some workarounds (see if Buffer can help), but by and large you'll not be able to do what you want.

In the past when I'd done something similar, I had found a service (unfortunately, I forget the name) which could make an RSS feed out of my public G+ posts, and I used that to in turn post to Facebook and Twitter. Everything else I've seen about posting the same thing to multiple social networks required starting from G+ and moving out from there.